# Animate a View From Bottom to Top Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working with a view that need to be animate from bottom to top when press a button.

I tried with `TranslateTo` function but not succeeded.

[image]

this is the view I need to implement.

any suggestions?

````
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <Button Text="Scan" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>
    </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="ScanView" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,0.3" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Label Text="Animate" HeightRequest="100"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>``` 

ScanView.IsVisible = true;
            ScanView.Rotation = 0;
            await Task.WhenAll(
            ScanView.TranslateTo(0, 0, 2000, Easing.SinInOut));
````

Comment: TranslateTo is the right approach. Could you please share us some code of your implementation to detect some pitfalls?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984983/xamarin-create-swipe-page-in-page/58989073#58989073

Comment: The TranslateTo value has to be negative to move up.

Comment: you should also try to wrap it in Device.BeginInvokeInMainUIThread()... I detect some issuses if I run animations in Tasks. Just a Hint.

Comment: https://www.heyraviteja.com/post/projects/xamarin-bottom-sheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems in the above code:

1. The IsVisible is set to False. Set it to True.
2. The Translation offset is set to 0, in the button click. Check the [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.viewextensions.translateto?view=xamarin-forms) for syntax. If Translating to Zero is intended, Set TranslateY of the `ScanView` to a value initially to its Height.

Fixed code:

**XAML**

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <Button Text="Scan" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="ScanView"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.3"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 TranslationY="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference ScanView}}"
                 IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        <Label Text="Animate" HeightRequest="100"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**CS**

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ScanView.TranslateTo(0, 0, 200);
    }
```

[image]

Hope this might help.